# Next JS Image working in local server but not working in production

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-storage, nextjs-image

So I have deployed my next js project on firebase hosting. I am using next js image tag to show an image from the firebase storage. I have added the firebase domain in the next.config.js file and it works fine on local server. But when i deploy it to firebase it gives an error of status 400.

this is my next.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
swcMinify: true,
images: {
  domains: ["firebasestorage.googleapis.com"],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And this is my image tag

```
  <Box sx={{ position: "relative", height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
       <Image src={imageUrl} layout="fill" alt="Message from lab" />
  </Box>
```

Comment: Can you share the link if it is deployed?

Comment: There could be a problem with the image path. Could you share an `imageURL` path that you get from firebase storage ?

Comment: @TusharShahi I cant share the link as it is an admin page for a live website.

Comment: @IGnyte  I don't think it is a problem with the URL, because the same URL works in localhost server and not on production server.

Comment: Is the error tagged 400 you say ? 400 aka "Bad Request"

Comment: @IGnyte Yeah it shows error status 400. It confuses me because the image url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting SSR on Firebase, you also need to add that config to Cloud Function as well to make sure that your server instance grabs that config.

```js
const server = next({
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  conf: {
    distDir: ".next",
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    images: {
      domains: ["firebasestorage.googleapis.com"],
      },
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: Where should I add this config?

Comment: @AkshatTiwari, you add this to your normal cloud functions instance. There are plenty of tutorials on how to setup cloud functions in your nextjs app. I randomly Google one example https://itnext.io/deploying-next-js-app-to-firebase-functions-eb473791d79e. And I highlighted the code where you place this config https://gist.github.com/muccy/33870cdc6cf86ef4819d81ddf6e44744#file-index-js-L12